# Unable to install fancyimpute for use in Jupyter

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, jupyter-notebook, fancyimpute

I have been trying to import fancyimpute on a Jupyter Notebook, as I am interested in using K Nearest Neighbors for data imputation purposes. However, I continue to get the error described in the screenshot.

I have already tried installing the following dependencies:

pip install ecos
pip install CVXcanon
pip install keras
pip install tensorflow
pip install fancyimpute

The error message is the following:

### Using TensorFlow backend.

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

[Screenshot Jupyter Notebook Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyhUw.png)

Comment: Please click the edit button on your question and paste the text of the error message there.  People will want to copy and paste that message, or eyeball it without having to leave this page.

Comment: @Mozahler sure, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error. Fixed by updating my numpy installation:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --user
```

The --user flag installs numpy to my home directory, to avoid using sudo with pip.

Answer (score 1):

using
`easy_install fancyimpute`

instead of pip install fancyimpute worked for me

Answer (score -1):

open anaconda **powershell prompt**

and run command

pip install fancyimpute