# Can not use MICE from fancyimputer (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am just trying to use the MICE function from fancyimpute.
Simple line of code *from fancyimpute import MICE* gives an error **cannot import name 'MICE'**

I did try to consult  https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute (i find it strange that MICE is nowhere to be found there but then people are implementing it https://medium.com/logicai/5-useful-python-packages-from-kaggles-kernels-you-didn-t-know-existed-part-2-4b35ba2d812)
as well as similiar problems on stack concerning MICE and importing problems but without of luck

Comment: IterativeImputer() should be the alternative, but it still baffles me how did others manage to implement it since it seems MICE does not exist in fancyimpute...

Comment: @joel I just used IterativeImputer() in the end. Which worked well.

Answer (score 4):

The below steps worked for me on MAC OSX.

1. Use easy_install fancyimpute in your terminal instead of pip install fancyimpute

[Unable to install fancyimpute for use in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217492/unable-to-install-fancyimpute-for-use-in-jupyter)

2. Use 'from fancyimpute import IterativeImputer as MICE' in your jupyter notebook. Looks like MICE is now called IterativeImputer.

https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute/issues/81

3. Use 'df1 = MICE().fit_transform(df)' on your dataframe. Looks like IterativeImputer does not have the function/method 'complete' anymore and the fit or fit_transform should be used with it instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
from fancyimpute import IterativeImputer as MICE

MICE().fit_transform(df)
```